# How to apply paging in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

How to apply paging when fetch large data in Oracle ADF 12.2.1.4.0.
I think we need some config in ViewObject but I don't know how to do that. I cannot find out any introduction about this feature.

Answer (score 1):

In the VO you select the 'General' tab and open the tuning section. There you set the in batches of value to a number which should be bigger than the number of rows you show on the page and select 'Access Mode' as 'Range Paging'.
[image: Sample configuration]